# Drupal 6 won't send email, for account activation etc

Tags: php, email, drupal-6, smtp, send

I'm running my own LAMP server locally.

Something i need to setup?

Should it be able to send email using php-mail, 
without havin to configure smtp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah fixed it, well i didn't-one of our developers did.

Apparently Drupal only uses 'Send Mail' so you have to have it installed, wont use php-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Check your phpinfo() information for STMP and the port. Do a test.php file and try to execute this.

```
mail('email@example.com', 'My Subject', 'Hello World');
```

Comment: May want to change the email address though, I hear example.com doesn't take too kindly to spam..

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/node/11570

That thread will help you out.

Drupal basically patches into the php mail function, so as with that you either need a mail server installed locally with your lamp setup, or to point apache towards an external or smtp server in your php.ini file.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference/research:
try the Drupal module [SMTP Authentication Support](http://drupal.org/project/smtp). I have yet to test it.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.